# loading html FORM asynchronously and adding it into DOM does'nt get validated by jQ validation plugin

Tags: forms, dom, jquery, jquery-validate

A simple get request made to url on my server which returns HTML of form which is put inside td element .

```
    $('form').validate();  // jquery validation plugin initialized 

    //user clicks some button and ajax request is send to load form       

  $.get(url,send,function(form){

           $('td').html(form).show();
                });
```

Problem is [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) do not work on the loaded form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form you are trying to validate does not exist when you initialise the plugin. Place the initialisation code in the success handler of the `$.get(...)`.